# How to get all text children of an element in cElementTree?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, celementtree

I'm using the `cElementTree` module in Python to get the text child of an `XML` tree, using the `text` property. But it seems to work only for the immediate text children (see below).

```
$ python
...
>>> import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
>>> root = ET.XML('<root><elm key="value">Some text</elm>More text</root>')
>>> root.text
>>> root = ET.XML('<root>Text 1<elm key="value">Text</elm>Text 2<elm2 />Text 3</root>')
>>> root.text
'Text 1'
>>>
```

Is it possible to retrieve all *immediate* text children of a given element (maybe as a list, i.e. `['More text']` and `['Text 1', 'Text 2', 'Text 3']` in the above examples) using the `cElementTree` module?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.itertext`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.itertext):

```
>>> import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
>>> root = ET.XML('<root><elm key="value">Some text</elm>More text</root>')
>>> list(root.itertext())
['Some text', 'More text']
>>> root = ET.XML('<root>Text 1<elm key="value">Text</elm>Text 2<elm2 />Text 3</root>')
>>> list(root.itertext())
['Text 1', 'Text', 'Text 2', 'Text 3']
```

**UPDATE**

To get immediate text children, you also need to access `tail` of child nodes:

```
>>> root = ET.XML('<root><elm key="value">Some text</elm>More text</root>')
>>> ([root.text] if root.text else []) + [child.tail for child in root]
['More text']
>>> root = ET.XML('<root>Text 1<elm key="value">Text</elm>Text 2<elm2 />Text 3</root>')
>>> ([root.text] if root.text else []) + [child.tail for child in root]
['Text 1', 'Text 2', 'Text 3']
```

Comment: See my edit - I only want to retrieve the *immediate* text children, so the result is `['More text']` and `['Text 1', ''Text 2', 'Text 3']` for the two examples.

Comment: @Sumit, Thank you for your feedback. I updated the answer accordingly.